# When trying to return a specific column from my matrix, R does not give the right results back

Tags: r, matrix

I've created a matrix which looks like this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    5    5    4  1.0    1    0    0
[2,]    5    2    0  2.0    0    2    3
[3,]    4    1   -1  2.0   -1   -1   -1
[4,]   36   37   -1  0.5   -1   -1   -1
```

When I ask my function to return a specific column, like this:

```
return( tree[,2])
```

It returns the value: [1]  4  0 -1 -1, which obviously is not the same value given by the matrix. This also happens when returning the value of [,3], where it gives [1]  0  3 -1 -1. It seems columns are skipped in the matrix. What could be the problem here?

I need the matrix to use its values in the next part of my code, with this problem I can not continue and I could not find this problem elsewhere.

Data

```
structure(c(5, 5, 4, 36, 5, 2, 1, 37, 4, 0, -1, -1, 1, 2, 2, 
0.5, 1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 2, -1, -1, 0, 3, -1, -1), .Dim = c(4L, 7L))
```

dput(tree) information, as requested below:

```
`structure(c(1, 2, 2, 0.5, 1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 2, -1, -1), .Dim = c(4L, 
3L))
structure(c(5, 2, 1, 37, 4, 0, -1, -1, 1, 2, 2, 0.5, 1, 0, -1, 
-1, 0, 2, -1, -1), .Dim = 4:5)
structure(c(5, 5, 4, 36, 5, 2, 1, 37, 4, 0, -1, -1, 1, 2, 2, 
0.5, 1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 2, -1, -1, 0, 3, -1, -1), .Dim = c(4L, 
7L))`
```

EDIT 2:
I'm trying to build a classification tree where as an output I would like to return Nclass0, Nclass1, BestS and Best I for each split made in an other function tree.bestsplit.

```
  `tree.grow = function(matrix, class, nmin=2, minleaf=1) {
   nClass0 = length(which(class == 0))
   nClass1 = length(which(class == 1))

  if(nrow(matrix) < nmin || nClass0 == 0 || nClass1 == 0){
  return(list(nClass0, nClass1, BestS = -1, BestR = -1))
  }  
  bestR = -1
  bestS = 0
  bestI = 0

  for (i in 1:ncol(matrix)) {
  result = tree.bestsplit(matrix[,i], class, minleaf)
  if(result[2] > bestR) {
  bestR = result[2]
  bestS = result[1]
  bestI = i
  }
  }

  if(is.null(bestI)){
  return(list(nClass0, nClass1))
  }

  tree <- data.frame(nClass0, nClass1, bestI, bestS)

  left = matrix[matrix[,bestI] <= bestS,]
  leftClass = class[matrix[,bestI] <= bestS]

  right = matrix[matrix[,bestI] > bestS,]
  rightClass = class[matrix[,bestI] > bestS]

  leftG = tree.grow(left, leftClass, nmin, minleaf)
  rightG = tree.grow(right, rightClass, nmin, minleaf)

  Lijst = list(nClass0, nClass1, bestI, bestS, leftG, rightG)

  tree <- unlist(Lijst)

  tree <- matrix(tree, nrow = 4)

  return(tree)
  }

   `
```

Comment: You need to provide the output of `dput(tree)` in your question. Until you do that and I can reproduce this I do not believe your claims.

Comment: Not completely sure what you meant by dput(tree), but added the information. Thanks agenis for editing, this is my first time using this platform, so my post might not be completely in complience with standards.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. You'll have to provide more context, such as the function you are using.

Comment: Added code from the main function. It's probably very messy, but i'm not a very experienced R user.